# How do I  Install Drivers for an ALFA AWUS036NHR?

Tags: installation, networking, drivers, command-line

I am very new to Ubuntu and I really need to get this USB wireless running.  I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit on a virtual machine. It comes with some instructions for setting up the drivers, but as far as I know that is just to make the driver yourself and I'm not at that level yet.

If someone could tell me how to install the drivers, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions probably reference the `make` or `./configure` commands.  Unfortunately, if the drivers are not already in Ubuntu, you have to `make`, or build-from-source the drivers, and then continue to follow the installation instructions they provide you within the driver files.  I'd follow their instructions, including running `make` and installing the driver files per their instructions, because the drivers will need to be build before being usable.